# How to add country code dynamically for entering phone number in expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo

Use case: In the UI, I want to enter my phone number (country code+ number)
Field 1: Country code (Drop down)
Field 2: Phone number ( Text Input)
Question: Is there any library that I can use to  search/select the country code from the drop down?

Environment: Expo React Native Managed Workflow

I have seen many available for bare workflow, however not seen any library to work in managed workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually make an array of the country list with the object of country code, country name, and country flag and then you can load that array in your dropdown.

Here is the example JSON data

```
[{countryName:'IN',countryCode:'+91', countryFlagName:'INDIAN_FLAG.png'},{countryName:'PK',countryCode:'+92', countryFlagName:'PAK_FLAG.png'}]
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is there pre-built library which you know of so that I can use it ?

Comment: I haven't found any library which can perform this task on Expo React Native Managed Workflow. So you have to manually manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Mantu's answer you can use [react-native-country-picker-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-country-picker-modal) to fetch the list of all countries with phone codes.

eg:

```
import {getAllCountries} from "react-native-country-picker-modal";

export default YourComponent() {
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllCountries().then((countries) => {
      console.log(
        "getAllCountries RESPONSE:",
        JSON.stringify(countries, null, " ")
      );
    });
  }, []);
  ...
}
```

Sample Object:

```
{
 "cca2": "PK",
 "currency": [
  "PKR"
 ],
 "callingCode": [
  "92"
 ],
 "region": "Asia",
 "subregion": "Southern Asia",
 "flag": "flag-pk",
 "name": "Pakistan"
}
```